# How can I use the Memory inside NICs?

Tags: networking, memory, nic, rdma

As explained in this paper *ASPLOS'22 The benefits of general-purpose on-NIC memory*

Comment: what is the real question here? are you asking how is the `SRAM memory of NIC used for packet processing in DPDK`? If yes, simple answer it is same way how Linux, BSD or WIndows uses the NIC for RX and TX packets. If the question is related to `RDMA`, please rephrase to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the code in the artifact at:
https://github.com/BorisPis/nicmem-asplos22-artifact

In essence, there's an API exposed in upstream rdma-core's libibverbs that exposes it, and you can see the dpdk patches for an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering it. I've already found the API docs (https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/OFEDv502180/Programming#Programming-DeviceMemoryProgramming); 

And the *NICMEM* is really an excellent job!